# How to check if user x sent more than two messages in the chat and hide his name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a chat built in JavaScript, and I have a problem. I recently coded to add user names on top of messages, and this works perfectly, but the problem is that I don’t know how to hide the user’s name when he sends more than one message, I’ve already tried it using CSS, but using CSS it would become very confusing, only the name of a user would appear, is there any way I can do this using JavaScript? I am trying to do a chat like messenger, I would like it to work as follows:

If the user Bob sends more than one message, then his name must appear above the first message only

If the user Mark sends a message, then his name must appear on top of his first message, and not in the following messages of the same

How can I do this using JavaScript? I believe that using CSS this is almost impossible, you can check this

I'm using PHP Sessions to show the username in JavaScript, so I think that something like *LocalStorage* will not help me too much, if someone can help me, please do not use cookies or JavaScript sessions, try to create a variable that has a name if possible

[image: Illustrative picture]

```js
var chat = document.getElementById('chat');
var send = document.getElementById('send');

function SendMessage(who, data) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.classList.add(who);
  var userName = document.createElement('div');
  userName.classList.add('user');
  userName.textContent = 'Mark';
  li.appendChild(userName);
  var msg = document.createElement('div');
  msg.classList.add('msg');
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = data.message;
  msg.appendChild(span);
  li.appendChild(msg);

  chat.appendChild(li);
}

send.addEventListener('click', function() {
  SendMessage('him', {
    message: 'I love to code'
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style-type: none
}

ul li {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul li .user {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: grey;
}

.him { align-self: flex-start; }
.me  { align-self: flex-end; }

.msg {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.him .user { text-align: left;  margin-left: 10px; }
.me  .user { text-align: right; margin-right: 10px; }

.him .msg { background: yellow; }
.me  .msg { background: #0084ff; color: #fff; }




.center{
    background-color:black;
    /* width:500px; */
    height:100vh;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    width:100vw;
    overflow: auto;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
    <ul id="chat">
        <li class="him">
          <div class="user">Bob</div>
          <div class="msg">
            <span>Hello World</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="me">
          <div class="user">Me</div>
          <div class="msg">
            <span>Hello World</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="him">
          <div class="user">Bob</div>
          <div class="msg">
            <span>How to hide the name after x user sends more than one message</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="him">
          <div class="user">Bob</div>
          <div class="msg">
            <span>How to hide the name after x user sends more than one message</span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button id="send" style="float:right;">Send</button>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check who sent last message, something like

```
if(lastUserName == currentUserName)
   addLI()
else
  addULwithLI();
```

This way you can create a ul > li.username

```
    <ul  class="him">
      <li class="user">Bob</li>
     <li>
      <div class="msg">
        <span>How to hide the name after x user sends more than one message</span>
      </div>
    </li>
     <li>
      <div class="msg">
        <span>How to hide the name after x user sends more than one message</span>
      </div>
    </li>
     <li>
      <div class="msg">
        <span>How to hide the name after x user sends more than one message</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

So when is different username add both ul li else just li.

Edit:

```
function SendMessage(who, userName, data) {
var lastUser = getLastUser();
if(userName == lastUser) {
  saveLastUser(userName);
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.classList.add(who);
  var msg = document.createElement('div');
  msg.classList.add('msg');
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = data.message;
  msg.appendChild(span);
  li.appendChild(msg);
  
  chat.appendChild(li);
 }else{
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.classList.add(who);
  var userName = document.createElement('div');
  userName.classList.add('user');
  userName.textContent = 'Mark';
  li.appendChild(userName);
  var msg = document.createElement('div');
  msg.classList.add('msg');
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = data.message;
  msg.appendChild(span);
  li.appendChild(msg);
  saveLastUser()
  chat.appendChild(li);
  }
}
function  getLastUser() {
  // get last user from saved in db.
 return localStorage.getItem('lastUser');
}
function  saveLastUser(username) {
  // save last user from saved in db.
  localStorage.setItem('lastUser',username);
}
```

Also make js to produce html like I mention because its easy to add li to Ul as thread of same person

Comment: This seems to be useful, but confusing to me. So should I change the classes in CSS and create new functions in JavaScript? And what value to store in these variables in the control structure?

Comment: I made an edit, its abstract code and it works only on your browser since its saving to local storage. set and get should be from db, along with message. I am trying to put you on right direction as logic. play with that.

Comment: Please tell me how can I work with this using variables in PHP? I don't want to work with local JavaScript storage, since my application is not entirely created in JavaScript, is it possible to do this using PHP variables?

Comment: Ajax call. $ajax.request('/somepath/);  to be honest its more complicated that you think and bette check any chat tutorial like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xq8LIOj6AWI

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for helping me, you managed to create a good logic and I believe that it can help me in the future if I study more deeply. Thanks a lot!